# Is it possible to use a custom starting position with NippleJS

Tags: vue.js

I need to use a virtual joystick that works well with touch and also works in Vue, so NippleJS seemed like a good option but I also need the starting point of the control itself to be at the bottom of the joystick. Currently the starting point is always at the middle, but I want the User to only be able to go upwards basically. Does anyone know how to do that either in NippleJS or does someone know an alternative library?

```
const imgJoystickL = nipplejs.create({
                zone: document.getElementById('img-nipple-L'),
                color: 'rgb(50, 50, 50)',
                mode: 'static',
                position: {
                    top: marginTop,
                    left: '5px'
                },
                lockY: true,
                size: 200,
                shape: 'square',
            });
```

That's how I currently create the joystick.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep the jsnipple in its default position at the center and detect when the angle is up.

```
function YourMoveUpFunction(){
//do something
}

imgJoystickL.on("move", (evt, data) => {
  
  if(data.direction.angle == "up") 
    YourMoveUpFunction()
});
```